# What is the error in the if statement in this bash script? 

Tags: bash, shell

What is the problem with the following shell script? I'm getting

```
[: too many arguments
```

error

```
#!/bash
var1=10;
var2=20;
if [ $var1 % 2 -eq 0 ] -a [ $var2 %5 -eq 0 ];
then
    #something
fi
```

Comment: Why do you believe that `%` and `%5` are valid arguments for `[`?

Comment: how do we get the modulous (I am a newbie)

Answer (score 5):

First, the `[` command only does comparisons. You have to perform calculations separately. For example:

```
var1mod=$((var1 % 2))
if [ $var1mod -eq 0 ]; then
```

However, since you appear to be writing your script for bash, you can use a different command and avoid the extra step:

```
if (( var1 % 2 == 0 )); then
```

And second, you cannot chain commands with `-a`. This only works as an argument to `[`. But outside it, you must use `&&`.

Three different variants:

```
if [ $var1mod -eq 0 -a $var2mod -eq 0 ]; then
if [ $var1mod -eq 0 ] && [ $var2mod -eq 0 ]; then
if (( var1 % 2 == 0 )) && (( var2 % 2 == 0 )); then
if (( var1 % 2 == 0 && var2 % 2 == 0 )); then
```

Always remember, the syntax of `if` is a simple `if command; then command; fi`. This means that `[` in `if [` is just the name of a command like `ls` or `echo`.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be confusing Conditional Evaluation with Arithmetic Evaluation. `%` is an operator in Arithmetic Evaluation, not Conditional Evaluation. See the `bash(1)` man page sections for those topics. `[...]` is for Conditional Evaluation, whereas `((...))` is for Arithmetic Evaluation.

Not to mention that your shebang line is wrong, unless for some reason you installed a copy of bash at the root level of your boot drive.

Last but not least, a newline is the same as a semicolon.  You don't need to end a line with a semicolon in shell scripting.  The semicolon just exists to allow you to put two statements on one line.

Here's a cleaned up version of your script:

```
#!/bin/bash

VAR1=10
VAR2=20
if (( (VAR1 % 2 == 0) && (VAR2 % 5 == 0) )); then
    : #something (colon is a no-op)
fi
```

Comment: `-a` has two meanings; `EXPR -a EXPR` *is* a logical AND.